# How can I inspect this slice of this array in gdb?

Tags: arrays, gdb

I am in a GDB debugging session and I have an array of length 20,000. Most of the elements are zero but there is a couple of them at around index `10000` which are of interest. Unfortunately, when I say `p the_array[10000]@30` or something I get "only values in memory can be extended with '@'". How can I visualize a region of that array without having to manually request each index over a range of say 40-50 elements?

Answer (score 26):

I would expect this to work.  And it does work for me.  I have this little program:

```
int x[10000];
```

Now in gdb:

```
(gdb) p x[50]@3
$2 = {0, 0, 0}
```

Many details are missing from your question.  Maybe your gdb has a bug.  Or maybe your array is odd in some respect.  The gdb version and things like "whatis the_array" might be interesting.

Comment: Something important to note about this, because it has tripped me up more times than I care to admit...  when you do a slice of, say, array c[9]@5 to get elements 9 through 13 of array c, they won't come back indexed as [9,10,11,12,13].  They will come back indexed as [0,1,2,3,4].  So index 0 would be c[9], index 1 would be c[10], etc.

This has thrown me off many times when I would put something like c[9]@5 as a watch expression in VS when debugging with GDB and get back results indexed at 0.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like we cannot use addresses to extend the memory regions

```
(gdb) p (struct tfc *)0x1d88a010@100
Only values in memory can be extended with '@'.
```

But this works fine

```
(gdb) p *tfc->buckets@100
$87 = {0x0 <repeats 49 times>, 0x7f3b63a1b060, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f3b21816c90, 0x0 <repeats 18 times>, 0x7f3ae97f9e80, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x7f3b49c96760, 0x0 <repeats 14 times>, 0x7f3adb16d8f0}
```

Comment: nah, you can. `print ((unsigned long long*)0x7ffff6ffb000)[0]@20` for numbers, `print ((void **)0x7ffff6ffb000)[0]@20` for pointers, just replace the type with whatever is in the array.